# jQuery autocomplete: want to change the input field's value and retrigger the search

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I have this nice working autocomplete using the [Rails3 jQuery auto-complete plugin](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete), but in an "after-hook" (don't know if this is the right description for it) I want to alter the value and retrigger the autocomplete.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $('#position_name').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data) {
    // Remove the placeholder from the value and set selection range into it!
    if(this.value.indexOf('"(.+)"') >= 0) {
      placeholder_content_index = this.value.length - 5;
      this.value = this.value.substr(0, placeholder_content_index) + '"';
      this.setSelectionRange(placeholder_content_index, placeholder_content_index);
    }
  });
</script>
```

So far everything works except retriggering the autocomplete call. I've tried stuff like `$("#position_name").change();`, `this.change()`, `this.trigger("change")`, etc., but it didn't work. Thanks a lot for pointing me into the right direction!

Comment: which plugin are using for autocomplete

Comment: jQuery autocomplete (see title and tag). :)

Comment: Ah, the rails3 version (added it to my question).